# аккордеон добавить класс к родителу

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Решил воспользоваться готовым аккордеон, подскажите как к родителю `(li)` элемента `a.active` добавить `class` при нажатии на `a.active` и убирать этот же класс у всех `li`.

```js
(function($) {
    $('.accordion > li:eq(0) a').addClass('active').next().slideDown();

    $('.accordion a').click(function(j) {
        var dropDown = $(this).closest('li').find('p');

        $(this).closest('.accordion').find('p').not(dropDown).slideUp();

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();

        j.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <a>Lorem ipsum</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Repellat Odit Aliquid</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Dolor sit Amet</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- / accordion -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так. Хотя на мой взгляд, лучше назначать класс только для li

```js
(function($) {
    $('.accordion > li:eq(0) a').addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    //добавляем класс первому li при запуске аккордеона
    $('.accordion > li:eq(0)').addClass('your-class');

    $('.accordion a').click(function(j) {
        var dropDown = $(this).closest('li').find('p');

        $(this).closest('.accordion').find('p').not(dropDown).slideUp();

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').removeClass('your-class');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
       $(this).parents('.accordion').find('.your-class').removeClass('your-class');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('your-class');
        }

        dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();

        j.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  }
.your-class{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <a>Lorem ipsum</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Repellat Odit Aliquid</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Dolor sit Amet</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsum, fuga, in, obcaecati magni ullam nobis voluptas fugiat tenetur voluptatum quas tempora maxime rerum neque deserunt suscipit provident cumque et mollitia ex aspernatur porro minus sapiente voluptatibus eos at perferendis repellat odit aliquid harum molestias ratione pariatur adipisci. Aliquid, iure.</p>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- / accordion -->
```